# Implement Sleep Sort

Tags: code-golf, sorting, concurrency

Sleep Sort is an integer sorting algorithm I found on the Internet. It opens an output stream, and for each input numbers in parallel, delay for the number seconds and output that number. Because of the delays, the highest number will be outputted last. I estimate it has O(n + m), where n is the number of elements and m is the highest number.

Here is the original code in Bash

```
#!/bin/bash
function f() {
    sleep "$1"
    echo "$1"
}
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    f "$1" &
    shift
done
wait
```

Here is the pseudocode

```
sleepsort(xs)
 output = []
 fork
   for parallel x in xs:
     sleep for x seconds
     append x to output
 wait until length(output) == length(xs)
 return output
```

Your task is to implement Sleep Sort as a function in the programming language of your choice. You can neglect any concurrency factors such as race conditions and never lock any shared resources. The shortest code wins. The function definition counts toward the code length.

The input list is limited to non-negative integers only, and the length of the input list is expected to reasonably long (test at least 10 numbers) so race conditions never happen.
and assuming race conditions never happen.

Comment: What counts towards the length? Complete programs including IO or just the relevant routine?

Comment: A problem with this. Depending on the order of the list, you might not read the entire list before the first value is printed. For example, a large list that takes 45 seconds to read, the first value is 2 and the last value is 1. The thread to print 1 might be executed after the 2 is printed. Oops - the output is no longer sorted properly. There might be some workarounds - creating the threads and then starting them after the whole list is read (but that will lead to longer code, against the golf). I wonder if someone can provide a golf that addresses this potential issue...I'm going to try.

Comment: Incidentally, what makes this algorithm *really* interesting is that there actually exist real-life applications. For instance, DNA sequencing (Sanger sequencing) depends on something like this to sort DNA fragments according to their length (and more generally, every electrophoresis does something similar). The difference is that sequencing is performed physically, not in a computer.

Comment: I hate to be the one to rain on everybody's parade, but doesn't this just offload complexity onto the OS scheduler in a way that's probably O(N^2)?

Comment: I wonder weather you can implement this in a way it actually performs well. How would you have to figure out the amount of time it has to wait per step, so the numbers would be still placed in the right order?

Comment: I think there are physical sort algorithms that takes O(n) time but O(n) physical objects. Well, we can use melting candles and a tube to do it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_sort

Comment: Original source, since OP didn't credit it: http://dis.4chan.org/read/prog/1295544154 NSFW (yes, seriously.)

Comment: @Nils: Well - for N < 1000, a sleep 1s should be sufficient. If n > 1000, the user has to experiment and verify the solutions :) .

Comment: Typically, insertion sort is used afterwards to correct any errors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A kind of lame **Perl** attempt, <strike>59</strike> <strike>55</strike> <strike>52</strike> <strike>38</strike> **32 characters**:

`map{fork||exit print sleep$_}@a`

**Barebones: 25 Characters:**

...if you don't mind the sort results as die output:

`map{fork||die sleep$_}@a`

**With all the trimmings:**

(for maximum challenge compliance, **44** characters)

`sub t{map{fork||exit print sleep$_}@_;wait}`

If you let perl do the wait for you, **39** characters:

`sub t{map{fork||exit print sleep$_}@_}`

And again, if you don't mind `die()`, **32** characters...

`sub t{map{fork||die sleep$_}@_}`

Note that in Perl 6, or when the 'say' feature is declared, it is possible to replace the `print` function with `say`, saving a character in each instance. Obviously since `die` both terminates the forked process and writes the output, it remains the shortest solution.

Comment: you can stil run `perl-E` to enable 5.010 features like `say`

Comment: `(fork&&die sleep$_)for@a` works too

Answer (score 21):

**C**, 127 characters, a rather obvious solution:

```
main(int c,char**v){
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(c)
for(int i=1;i<c;++i){int x=atoi(v[i]);sleep(x);printf("%d ",x);}}
```

(Compiled with `gcc -std=c99 -fopenmp sort.c` and ignoring all warnings.)

Comment: Cool I really have to learn opemp

Comment: I would call that 93 characters (without command-line parsing and such), but it's impressive that you can do that in only 34 extra characters in C!

Comment: @KonradRudolph - You can save 6 bytes going backwards: `for(;c>=0;--c){int x=atoi(v[c]);`. Not sure if that's allowed.

Comment: @owacoder that would be `for(;--c;)...` to leave out `v[c]` and `v[0]` which are not part of the list, `v[c] == NULL` and `v[0] == "a.out"`

Answer (score 16):

### APL (<s>15</s> 13)

```
{⎕←⍵⊣⎕DL⍵}&¨⎕
```

What it does:

```
¨⎕       : for each element of the input
&        : do on a separate thread
⎕DL⍵    : wait approx. ⍵ seconds
⎕←⍵     : output ⍵
```

Comment: I see boxes instead of 3 characters.

Comment: @ArtemIce: There are supposed to be three boxes (quads). Two are the I/O variable (reading it gets input, and writing to it prints output), and one is in the name of the `⎕DL` function which is sleep.

Comment: Discussing on the APL Orchard, we wonder if `⌊∘⎕DL&¨` would count, for 7; removing the quad on the right makes it a function, ⎕DL is in the ISO SPEC for APL as delaying for "not less than" the time, so flooring its return value of "time actually delayed for" should be valid.

Answer (score 15):

### Ruby 1.9, 32 characters

As a function:

```
s=->a{a.map{|i|fork{p sleep i}}}
```

If we can just use a predefined variable, it reduces to 25 characters:

```
a.map{|i|fork{p sleep i}}
```

Comment: You can save quite some chars by using `Thread.new{p sleep i}` to print the output.

Comment: @Ventero, I'm only just learning Ruby and I'd like to know how you would run this lambda function or more specifically how you give this an input. Is it possible to run with IRB? Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

**JavaScript**, 65 characters *(depending on whether you use `console.log` or something else for outputting the result)*

```
a.map(function(v){setTimeout(function(){console.log(v)},v*1000)})
```

This assumes that `a` is an array of non-negative integers and that `map()` exists on the array prototype (JavaScript 1.6+).

Comment: You can probably shave off two or even three characters by multiplying with 10 (or 9) instead of 1000, without compromising correctness.

Comment: @Konrad: Yes, I think that would work. I just took the "one second" from the question.

Comment: If the one second is intended to remain, you can probably use `1e3` instead.

Comment: @Tomalak, `alert` is JavaScript's blocking output, `prompt` is JavaScript's blocking input, and `confirm` is JavaScript's blocking binary input. If JS were to be written on the command line, those would be the calls you would use.

Comment: @zzzzBov, using blocking output would almost certainly be a bad idea for this task.

Comment: @Peter Taylor, it would make no difference. The subsequent `alert` calls will be performed in the order that they were called. Consider `alert` just duping data to an output buffer.

Comment: @zzzzBov, it's the order in which they're called which I'm worried about - unless the JS spec has strong guarantees about the order in which setTimeout-enqueued thunks are called.

Comment: @Peter Taylor, the event loop mandates that all actions/events are queued. If an event is called while the script is blocked, it will wait its turn to execute. This is well defined behavior although it can lead to some serious issues with functions like `setInterval` which will continue to be called while the script is blocked, creating more calls that take longer than the duration of the interval leading to a constant block.

Comment: @Peter: JavaScript is strictly single-threaded. All events are processed in the order they were queued, setTimeout() is no exception. FWIW, I had more "append to a DOM element" in my mind than "alert". For things like node.js, I'm certain that "output to the console" also exists. My point was that the 65 characters might vary depending on what function you call.

Comment: How does it destroy the original array?

Comment: @minitech You are right, it doesn't. My mistake. I'll correct the post.

Comment: Even better: `setTimeout("console.log(v)",v*1e4)`

Comment: a.map(v=>{setTimeout(()=>{v},v*1)})

Answer (score 9):

Four tries in Erlang:

Output to the console, have taken the liberty to do this each `9ms * Number` since this is plenty enough to make it work (tested on a Atom embedded board = slow):

**Needs 60 chars**

```
s(L)->[spawn(fun()->timer:sleep(9*X),io:write(X)end)||X<-L].
```

Output to the console is total un-Erlangish, so we send a message to process `P` instead:

**Needs 55 chars**

```
s(P,L)->[spawn(fun()->timer:sleep(9*X),P!X end)||X<-L].
```

Sending after a time can also be done differently (this even works with `1ms * Number`):

**Needs 41 chars**

```
s(P,L)->[erlang:send_after(X,P,X)||X<-L].
```

Actually this is a bit unfair since the built in function `send_after` is a late comer and needs the namespace `erlang:` prefixed, if we consider this namespace imported (done on module level):

**Needs 34 chars**

```
s(P,L)->[send_after(X,P,X)||X<-L].
```

Answer (score 7):

## Python - 81 <del>93</del> <del>148</del> <del>150</del> <del>153</del>

Tweaking @BiggAl's code, since that's the game we're playing....

```
import threading as t,sys
for a in sys.argv[1:]:t.Timer(int(a),print,[a]).start()
```

**... or 97 <del>175</del> with delayed thread starting**

```
import threading as t,sys
for x in [t.Timer(int(a),print,[a]) for a in sys.argv[1:]]:x.start()
```

---

Takes input via the command line, ala

```
./sleep-sort\ v0.py 1 7 5 2 21 15 4 3 8
```

---

As with many python golfs, there comes a point where the code is compact enough that aliasing variables to shorten names doesn't even save characters.

This one is funky though because it aliases sys and threading BOTH as t, so sys.argv becomes t.argv. Shorter than from foo import *, and a net character savings! However I suppose Guido wouldn't be pleased...

<del>Note to self - learn c and stop golfing in python.</del> HOLY COW THIS IS SHORTER THAN THE C SOLUTION!

Comment: I managed to make some tweaks, but the formatting doesn't show up nicely in comments so I made my own answer. `daemon` doesn't need setting unless you're starting this as a daemon, and it's shorter to use positional args, esp. if you alias `None` to `N`

Comment: Oh and the first one doesn't work for me under 2.7.1, as `j` seems to end up as `False` - a side-effect of trying to do too much in one line?

Comment: shit I didn't realise you could import multiple modules to the same alias - I could actually think of some uses for that where I have multiple subclasses of the same custom base class lying about in seperate sub-modules. If we can shave off another 30 it's shorter than bash... But I don't think that'll happen.

Comment: Argh the reason why I didn't know is because you can't - I just tried running it and threading is not aliased, it's just called threading. It's sys that is aliased to t... Did you try running this? It's only an extra 2 chars on each though to import `as t,s` and then change to use `s` for `sys`

Comment: Argh you can't even do that, it's `import threading as t, sys as s`

Comment: You called me on it, I only did one incomplete test before I posted this solution. If my char count holds,     import threading as t, sys as s is still better so net victory

Comment: why don’t you use the `print` function instead of `sys.stdout.write`?

Comment: `for x in [t.Timer(int(a),print,[a]) for a in sys.argv[1:]]:x.start()` can become `for x in[t.Timer(int(a),print,[a])for a in sys.argv[1:]]:x.start()` by removing useless espaces to save 2 bytes

Answer (score 7):

### C# - 137 characters

Here is an answer in C# (updated with degrees of parallelism as commented)

```
void ss(int[]xs){xs.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(xs.Length).Select(x=>{Thread.Sleep(x);return x;}).ForAll(Console.WriteLine);}
```

Comment: You’ll need to specify `WithDegreeOfParallelism` for this to work, analogously to the `num_threads` in my OpenMP C code.

Comment: 120 bytes: `void m(int[] l){foreach(var i in l){var t=new Thread(()=>{Thread.Sleep(int.Parse(s));Console.Write(s);});t.Start();}}}`

Comment: @MrPaulch Note that you need to join the threads again, if you want your program to have the expected behaviour

Comment: Why? The longest running thread will keep the process alive.

Answer (score 7):

### Java (aka never wins at codegolf) : <s>234</s> <s>211</s> 187 chars

```java
public class M{public static void main(String[]s){for(final String a:s)new Thread(){public void run(){try{sleep(Long.parseLong(a));}catch(Exception e){}System.out.println(a);}}.start();}}
```

ungolfed:

```java
public class M {
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        for(final String a:s) new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(Long.parseLong(a));
                } catch(Exception e){}
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Joey thanks for setting it straight.

Comment: The class can be non-public, saving 7 chars.

Comment: You could also declare `throws Throwable` and get rid of the `catch` clause.

Comment: I think you can save 2 bytes by replacing `Long.parseLong` with `Long.valueOf`.

Comment: I know it's been 6.5 years, but you can golf some parts: `public` and `final` can be removed; `class M{public static void main` can be `interface M{static void main` (Java 8+); `Long.parseLong(a)` can be `new Long(a)` (resulting in **165 bytes**)

Comment: would `enum M` work?

Comment: @MilkyWay90 I'm pretty sure that shortcut works in Java 5 and 6, but not in Java 7 and later. I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 6):

## ColdFusion (8+), 109 bytes

```
<cfloop array="#a#" index="v"><cfthread><cfthread action="sleep" duration="#v*1000#"/>#v#</cfthread></cfloop>
```

Ungolfed:

```
<cfloop array="#a#" index="v">
  <cfthread><cfthread action="sleep" duration="#v*1000#"/>#v#</cfthread>
</cfloop>
```

This assumes that `<cfoutput>` is in effect. A few characters could be saved by writing it all on one line.

Answer (score 6):

#### Scala - <strike>42</strike> 40 characters (special case)

If you have a thread pool at least the size of the number of list elements:

```
a.par.map{i=>Thread.sleep(i);println(i)}
```

#### Scala - 72 characters (general)

```
a.map(i=>new Thread{override def run{Thread.sleep(i);println(i)}}.start)
```

Comment: afaik you don’t use `{}` when staying on one line.

Comment: @flying sheep - You can omit `{}` with one _statement_, but you still need it to group things separated by `;`, one line or no.  And you can write multi-line statements without `{}` in some cases (if/else for instance).

Comment: oh, i didn’t mean you can omit them, but that you can use `()` for one-liners instead. it’s a matter of taste there, i think. (i just don’t really get why `()` are supported at all when `{}` superseed them. maybe to not alienate java users instantly). Scala is cool, but defining code blocks by indentation is clearly superior. (and so, the religious war ensues ;))

Comment: @flying sheep - You're misinformed.  You can use `()` for single statements.  Try entering `(1 to 9).map(i => {val j = i+1; i*j})` in the REPL and then see what happens if you use `(1 to 9).map(i => (val j = i+1; i*j))`.

Comment: true, but i only referred to for expressions and stuff. Sorry, I hate writing stuff without being able to use linebreaks ;)

Comment: @flying sheep - Agreed about line breaks, but there are no `{}` that can be replaced with `()` in my answer, so why did you bring it up?

Comment: Oh, crap, you’re right. It’s lrn2read for me, I guess :)

Comment: But there was a set of `()`s that could be replaced by `{}`!

Answer (score 5):

### Javascript  - 52 characters

```
for(i in a)setTimeout("console.log("+a[i]+")",a[i])
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf.SE! I have formatted you answer for you, in particular indenting your code by four space to make it display as code. You'll find other formatting help in the sidebar of the edit page.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell - 143 characters

```
import Control.Concurrent
import System
d=threadDelay
f x=d(10^6*x)>>print x
g s=mapM(forkIO.f)s>>d(10^6*maximum s+1)
main=getArgs>>=g.map read
```

This probably could be made a shorter by taking input on stdin if that were an option, but it's late and either way, it's still 104 characters for the function itself.

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge-98, <strike>38</strike> 31 bytes

I know this is an old challenge, but I just recently discovered both sleepsort and 2D languages, had an idea about how to combine them, and looked for a place to post it, so here we are.

```
&#vt6j@p12<'
v:^ >$.@
>:!#^_1-
```

The main IP reads a number (`&`), then hits the `t` which clones it: one proceeds on the same line and cycles, reading new numbers and generating new childs until it reaches EOF which terminates the sequence.
All the child processes get stuck in a closed loop (the `v` and `^` of the third column) until the main IP finishes reading the input and executes the sequence of commands `'<21p`, which puts the character `<` at position (1,2), overwriting the `^` and freeing all the child processes, which start to simultaneously cycle, reducing by 1 their number at each iteration. Since execution speed of different IPs is synchronized in befunge, they will terminate (and print their value) in order, sorting the input list.

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XUFMuKzHLcigwNLZS54rXc4jjilO2stE1jP//39BAwUjB0ELBXMHQSAEA) by moving the control flow around a bit.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party:

### Maple - <strike>91</strike> 83 characters

In 91:

```
M:=():use Threads in p:=proc(n)Sleep(n);:-M:=M,n;end:Wait(map(i->Create(p(i)),L)[])end:[M];
```

In 83:

```
M:=():use Threads in Wait(seq(Create(proc(n)Sleep(n);:-M:=M,n end(i)),i=L))end:[M];
```

(This needs Maple version 15, and expects the list to be sorted in L)

Answer (score 3):

### C, <strike>70</strike> 69 chars

Doesn't wait for child processes to return, otherwise works.

```
main(n) {
    while(~scanf("%d",&n)?fork()||!printf("%d\n",n,sleep(n)):0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 90

```
import Control.Concurrent
s::[Int]->IO()
s=mapM_(\x->forkIO$threadDelay(x*9999)>>print x)
```

I hope this meets all the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, 125 bytes

Used the depricated `sleep_ms` function so I don't need to write a long duration.

```rs
|p:Vec<u32>|p.into_iter().for_each(|i|{use std::thread::{spawn,sleep_ms};spawn(move||{sleep_ms(i*1000);println!("{}",i)});});
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e90408419661dd444e15e816786bc5a9)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 38 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(x=>setTimeout(alert,x*1e3,x))
```

Comment: This will wait milliseconds instead of seconds

Comment: You can use `alert` to save 6 bytes

Comment: @mousetail Oops, didn't catch that it was required to use seconds.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP 57 bytes

```
<?for(;$i=fgets(STDIN);)pcntl_fork()?:die($i.usleep($i));
```

pcntl_fork() is only available under linux.

Answer (score 2):

Bash (38):

```
xargs -P0 -n1 sh -c 'sleep $0;echo $0'
```

Edit: Floating-point from stdin, separated by spaces or newlines.

Answer (score 2):

## , 11 chars / 22 bytes

```
ïć⇝שĤ⇀ôa,a⸩
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin//interpreter.html?eval=true&input=%5B...Array%281e3%29%5D.map%28%28v%2Ci%29%3D%3Ei%29&code=%C3%AF%C4%87%E2%87%9D%D7%A9%C4%A4%E2%87%80%C3%B4a%2Ca%E2%B8%A9)</kbd>

`שĤ⇀ôa`, this looks cool.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell 7, 40 bytes

[Filters are a kind of function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7):

```
filter f{$args|% -Pa{sleep $_;$_}-Th 99}

PS C:\> f 3 2 1
1
2
3
```

It uses Powershell 7's [ForEach-Object -Parallel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/) feature, which defaults to 5 threads, so has `-ThrottleLimit 99` to make it at work for the required 10 numbers.

Comment: you can save this code `$args|% -Pa{sleep $_;$_}-Th 99` to a stanalone `.ps1` script file. This is a Powershell program.

Comment: @mazzy Nice! this question specifically asks for "a function" including the function definition, so I'm not sure if it counts - if it is valid, it's -10 and would put it around 3rd shortest, which would be good.

Comment: A file with a Powershell script is both a program and a function. So a code that works in a standalone `.ps1` file fits perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Just some tweaking from @rmckenzie 's version:

### Python delayed thread start in <del>155</del> <del>152</del> <del>114</del> <del>108</del> 107:

```
import sys, threading as t
for x in [t.Timer(int(a),sys.stdout.write,[a]) for a in sys.argv[1:]]:x.start()
```

### Python without delay in <del>130</del> <del>128</del> <del>96</del> <del>95</del> 93:

```
import sys,threading as t
for a in sys.argv[1:]:t.Timer(int(a),sys.stdout.write,[a]).start()
```

Managed a few more optimisations, using `Timer` instead of `Thread`, which has a more concise call and removed the need to import `time`. Delayed thread start method benefits from list comprehension as it removes the need to initialise the list seperately at the start, although it's two characters longer (`"["+"]"+" "-":"`) than the for loop so it's useless without delayed start, and you have to be careful to use a list rather than a generator, or you're not actually creating the timer threads until you chunk through the generator.

Does anyone else have any optimisations?

---

The trick with `as` helps, but in 2.7.1 you can only import one module into an alias, and after some playing about you can't even `import mod1,mod2 as a,b`, you have to `import mod1 as a, mod2 as b`. It still saves a few characters, but isn't quite the cure-all I thought it was... And in fact it's better to leave sys as sys. Aliasing threading still helps though...

Comment: you got me beat, have an upding. I like the x=[];x+=[]. Didn't know you could do that....

Comment: ... you could do this in 128 if you loose the spaces between the : [statement] in your loop and f(x)... somehow I got it to 127, but I think that's by not counting the final newline (which is legit in CG). Thought I'd give you the update rather than being a tool and stealing your code.

Comment: @rmckenzie go for it, I stole yours. I'm always interested in seeing CG'd python - I feel like I'm doing something very perverse considering the goals of the language...

Comment: Yeah, I'm honestly shocked by how legible most python golfs stay... at the cost of a "glass floor" of characters. Check this one out: import threading,sys as t

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 54

`(defn s[n](doseq[i n](future(Thread/sleep i)(prn i))))`

Comment: you can get rid of few characters by inlining omitting `defn` (its brackets + argument list: from 54 to 43 chrs), or use `fn` instead of `defn` => len-=2

so I'd say in clj its 43 :D

Answer (score 1):

## C++11, 229 bytes

```c++
#import<future>
#import<iostream>
using namespace std;int main(int a,char**v){auto G=new future<void>[a];while(--a){G[a]=move(async([=](){this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(atoi(v[a])));cout<<v[a]<<" "<<flush;}));}delete[]G;}
```

Ungolfed and usage:

```c++
#import<future>
#import<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int a,char**v){
 auto G=new future<void>[a];
 while(--a){
  G[a]=move(async(
   [=](){
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(atoi(v[a])));
    cout<<v[a]<<" "<<flush;
   }
  ));
 }
 delete[]G;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rust - 150 bytes

And this is why you don't code golf in Rust, it's more verbose than Java ;). Depends on external crate `crossbeam`, it would be even worse without it.

```
|x|{extern crate crossbeam;crossbeam::scope(|s|for&v in x{s.spawn(move||{std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(v));println!("{}",v)});})}
```

Complete test program:

```
fn main() {
    let z =
    |x|{extern crate crossbeam;crossbeam::scope(|s|for&v in x{s.spawn(move||{std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(v));println!("{}",v)});})}
    ;
    z(&[4, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 6, 10])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 41 bytes

```julia
!l=@sync l.|>i->@async sleep(i)println(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHH1qG4Mi9ZIUevxi5T184hEcwrzklNLdDI1CwoyswryckDsv4rRhsa6JjomOkY6xjqGOmY6ljoWOqY6xjE/gcA)

`@async` adds the task to the machine's scheduler queue, and `@sync` waits for all `@async`s to finish

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 72 bytes

```c
main(n){~scanf("%d",&n)?fork()?wait(main()):printf("%d ",n+sleep(n)):0;}
```

I chose clang but it also works on gcc.

1. takes input from stdin
2. fork()
3. if it's the child, then sleep (returns 0 if sleep succeeded, see `sleep(3)`) and print the number... if it's the parent call main recursively (which implicitly returns 0 since C99).
4. when there's no more input we return from `main()` and start waiting for the children, the children also call `wait()` a number of times depending on the recursion depth but they don't have any children so that fails immediately for them.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///PzcxM08jT7O6rjg5MS9NQ0k1RUlHLU/TPi2/KFtD0748MbNEA6xGU9OqoCgzrwSsRkFJJ0@7OCc1tQCoV9PKwLr2/39DAwUTBTMFYwVDBSMFUwULBUsFcwUDAA)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of boring, port of C#, just to get started with the language again:

**F# - 90 characters**

```
PSeq.withDegreeOfParallelism a.Length a|>PSeq.iter(fun x->Thread.Sleep(x);printfn "%A" x)
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 74

```
function(a){for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)setTimeout('alert('+a[i]+')',a[i]*1e3)}
```

or 71/65 characters with nonstandardness:

```
function(a){a.map(function(v){setTimeout('console.log('+v+')',v*1e3)})}
```

Comment: Even back in 2011 I think `function(a){a.map(function(v){setTimeout(console.log,v,v)})}` may have worked in at least one browser for 60 bytes. Of course these days you would write `a=>a.map(v=>setTimeout(console.log,v,v))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Tcl 8.6, 41 chars

```
lmap c $argv {after $c "puts $c"};vwait f
```

You have to kill it with `^C`

Answer (score 0):

## VB.NET 100 bytes

Because VB.Net requires single line lambdas to contain only one statement, this code has to have the multiple lines:

```
Array.ForEach(i, Async Sub(x)
Await Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(x*1000)
Console.WriteLine(x)
End Sub)
```

Ungolfed:

```
Option Strict Off

Sub Main(i() as String)
    Array.ForEach(i, Async Sub(x)
                         Await Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(x * 1000)
                         Console.WriteLine(x)
                     End Sub)
End Sub
```

---

However I'm not sure if you count imports statements in the byte counts because if you don't count them then I could write this:

## VB.NET 71 bytes

```
a.ForEach(i, Async Sub(x)
Await t.Delay(x*1000)
c.WriteLine(x)
End Sub)
```

Ungolfed:

```
Option Strict Off
Imports t = System.Threading.Tasks.Task
Imports c = System.Console
Imports a = System.Array

Sub Main(i() as String)
    a.ForEach(i, Async Sub(x)
                     Await t.Delay(x * 1000)
                     c.WriteLine(x)
                 End Sub)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 47 bytes

Assumes numbers are given on the command line...

`args.each{i->Thread.start{sleep(i*22)print i}}`

Answer (score 0):

**Mathematica, 34 or 36 bytes**

```
RunScheduledTask[Print@#,{#,1}]&/@
```

Just append the list to be sorted to the end of this code and evaluate. If it needs to be a valid function definition then it takes two extra bytes:

```
RunScheduledTask[Print@#,{#,1}]&/@#&
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 9, 82 bytes

```
i->{i.parallelStream().map(j->{Thread.sleep(j);System.out.println(j);return 0;});}
i->{                                                                             }  //lambda: arguments: List<int> i
    i.parallelStream().map(                                                    );   //iterate over each item in a parallel thread
                           j->{                                               }     //lambda: arguments: int j
                               Thread.sleep(j);                                     //sleep j milliseconds
                                               System.out.println(j);               //print that int
                                                                     return 0;      //just some return value to fullfil the requirements of map()
```

Comment: Some issues which practically mean this is an invalid solution. `Thread.sleep` throws `InterruptedException` (a checked exception that needs to be caught) which means this does not work. Also, streams don't run every element in a separate thread, and in fact because streams are lazy, this doesn't work at all as nothing is done with result of `map`. There is also no such thing as `List<int>` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

## Java - 106 bytes

```
l->l.forEach(x->new Thread(()->{try{Thread.sleep(x);System.out.println(x);}catch(Exception e){}}).start())
```

Complete test program:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class CG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<List<Integer>> sleepSort = l->l.forEach(x->new Thread(()->{try{Thread.sleep(x);System.out.println(x);}catch(Exception e){}}).start());
        sleepSort.accept(List.of(3423, 143, 4545, 2545, 764, 5121, 2333, 944, 6555, 1066));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

```
Ëe3 t{OpD
P
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=y2UzIHR7T3BEClA=&input=WzEwLDUwLDIwLDIsOTAsMyw0MCw3MiwxLDMyLDcsNDZd)

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
UmD{De3 t{OpD
P

UmD{  Map input array with the function...
De3 t{  Run the following function after D * 1000 milliseconds...
OpD       Print D with newline

P     Set "" as the thing to implicitly print
```

JS's `setTimeout` is obviously the winner. Unlike `setInterval` which is low-capped at 10ms, `setTimeout` doesn't have such an arbitrary limit.

If the delay need not be in seconds, the following works (and gives the result much faster):

### 8 bytes

```
Ët{OpD
P
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=y3R7T3BEClA=&input=WzEwLDUwLDIwLDIsOTAsMyw0MCw3MiwxLDMyLDcsNDZd)

Comment: You could overwrite the crud output by `N.t()` (_no_ idea why ETH  did that) and avoid the need for the "P" by [using `O.q()` instead](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=y2UzIHR7T3FE&input=WzEwLDUwLDIwLDIsOTAsMyw0MCw3MiwxLDMyLDcsNDZd). Each number would overwrite the previous one, though, which may not be allowed behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell) 6, 34 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{$(sleep $_;$_)&}|rcjb -wai
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24RrVaRaM4JzW1QEEl3lolXlOttqYoOStJQbc8MfP////G/w3/GwEA)

See [Background operator &](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7)

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 48 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{sajb{sleep $args;$args}-ar $_}|rcjb -wai
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24RrW6ODErqbo4JzW1QAEsZA0ma3UTixRU4mtripKzkhR0yxMz////b/zf8L8RAA)

where:

- `sajb` is the predefined alias for `start-job` and
- `rcjb` is the predefined alias for `receive-job`

The default `ThrottleLimit` is 32.